# Query works in Query studio but not in automation studio to add to a data extension

Tags: query

The following query worked in query studio but when I tried to use it in the automation to update a Data extension, I got the error "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key". The query is:

SELECT subscriberkey,emailaddress from _subscribers where subscriberkey not in (select subscriberkey FROM [_sent])

I have subscriberkey as the Primary Key. I tried the query with DISTINCT and still got the same error. What should be done?